# Call method from view and receive its value:

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got this method that returns a random word from the list:

```
public string GetRandom()
{
    var firstNames = new List<string> {"Hund", "Katt", "Hus", "Bil"};

    Random randNum = new Random();
    int aRandomPos = randNum.Next(firstNames.Count);//Returns a nonnegative random number less than the specified maximum (firstNames.Count).

    string currName = firstNames[aRandomPos];

    return currName;
}
```

In my view, I would like to be able to call this method and display the value it returns. 
I cant figure out how, I can call the method like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("GetRandom","GetRandom")
```

But how do I take care of its value and display it in the view?

Comment: Maybe you should add more tags to distinguish this question, like asp.net-mvc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear as though you will need to use Javascript in order to produce the effect that you describe in your latest comment.

1. Alter your `GetRandom` method to return a `JsonResult` instead of a `string`:

   ```
   public ActionResult GetRandom()
   { 
       var firstNames = new List<string> { "Hund", "Katt", "Hus", "Bil" };
       Random randNum = new Random();
       int aRandomPos = randNum.Next(firstNames.Count);
       string currName = firstNames[aRandomPos];
       return Json(currName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```
2. Use jQuery to retrieve the data and display it in the label *asynchronously* (without a page refresh) each time the button is clicked:

   ```
   <p id="randomName">Random Swag</p>
   <button id="randomButton">Generate Name</button>

   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script>
        $("#randomButton").click(function () {
            $.get('/Home/GetRandom', function (data) {
                $("#randomName").text(data);
            });
        });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: This was interesting, however, it calls the method directly on-load, I would like to control the call with a button if possible. Thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did exactly what i wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Put your method in a class that is derived from [Controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).

[ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), the first parameter is action name, the second parameter is controller name.

You want to call this way.

```
@Html.ActionLink("GetRandom", "GetRandom")
```

This is what you need to have.

```
public class GetRandomController : Controller
{
    public string GetRandom()
    {
        var firstNames = new List<string> { "Hund", "Katt", "Hus", "Bil" };

        Random randNum = new Random();
        int aRandomPos = randNum.Next(firstNames.Count);//Returns a nonnegative random number less than the specified maximum (firstNames.Count).

        string currName = firstNames[aRandomPos];

        return currName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now, the method is in my HomeController that inherits from controller. Do I have to make a new Controller for this to work?

Comment: @user2915962, if you put your method in HomeController, you can call this way `@Html.ActionLink("GetRandom", "Home")`. you want to create a separated controller or not, it's up to you..

Comment: I understand. And this calls the method GetRandom(), but how can I, in my view, display the value that is returned from the method?

Comment: @user2915962, what page do you want show your `GetNumber`? `localhost/Home/Index`?

Comment: Sure! The same page as I have the actionLink.

Comment: @user2915962, not sure whether you understand basic mvc, check my update whether you understand or not

Comment: Thank you Yuliam! Yes I think I got the basics. Thank you for tking the time to explain, @ByteBlast gave an answer that worked out perfectly! Thanks again for your time!